# D3 transitions - pause and resume with non-linear easing

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

Like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15845506/1696114), I have attempted to use this [guide](http://xaedes.de/dev/transitions/) to achieve pausing and resuming transitions in d3, but have had trouble understanding the author's explanation, this time for a different part of the guide (resuming non-linear transitions).

Say I have a transition:

```
d3.select("#circle")
    .attr("cx", 10)
    .attr("T", 0) // create attribute to represent progression through trans
        .transition()
        .duration(1000) // 1 second
        .ease("cubic-in-out")
        .attr("cx", 100)
        .attr("T", 1)
```

and a pause function:

```
function pause(){
    d3.select("#circle");
        .transition() // stops the current transition
        .duration( 0 ); 
}
```

What might my resume function look like?

Comment: you'll have to reverse-engineer the cubic-in-out equation so that given an intermediate value of the attribute you can calculate the temporal progress. then you'll have to write a custom tweening function to complete the transition from that point.

Comment: a simpler, although not fully accurate, approach would be to use a 'cubic-out' ease function.