# D3.js: Pause button not working (in a callback function used for animation)

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I'm trying to add the capability of pausing and resuming to my animation:
[image]

It shows the positions of trains (yellow) on a line. My data is nested, where the key is time period. It currently calls `render(t)` function every `interval` milliseconds. 
I've read [this guide](http://xaedes.de/dev/transitions/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845506/d3-transitions-pause-and-resume) about this, but I'm still lost as to how to apply it to my case.

I'd like to pause the animation, inspect trains attributes, then resume it.
Any help is appreciated!

```
currentTime = 0;
interval = 100;
var trainsHolder = svg.append('g')

 function render(t){

    trains = trainsHolder
            .selectAll('circle')
            .data(nested_train_data[t], function(d){ return d.car_id})

    // enter
    trains
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .each(setAttributes)

    // update
    trains
        .transition()
        .duration(interval)
        .each(setAttributes)

    // exit
    trains.exit().remove();

    // update timer
    timer_holder
        .select("text")
        .transition()
        .duration(interval)
        // .text("Time : " + String(t/60))
        .text(String(nested_train_data[t][0].Date.getHours()) + ":"  + String( nested_train_data[t][0].Date.getMinutes()))

    };

render(currentTime);

var callback = function () {
        return function () {
// my time increments are 60 seconds

            currentTime = currentTime + 60; 
            // console.log(currentTime);
            if (currentTime <= maxTime) {
                render(currentTime);
                d3.timer(callback(), interval);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }



    d3.timer(callback(), interval);
// NOT WORKING
$("#pauseBtn").click(function() {
        trainsHolder.selectAll('circle').transition().duration( 0 );
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking "pause" out of the picture, does the animation run properly? If so, the issue appears to be with your callback function. That is what drives the animation.

You want something like the following. The basic idea is that you advance the animation timer if and only if the simulation is not paused and hasn't exceeded the `maxTime`:

```
return function(elapsed) {
    paused = getPausedState();
    //use the elapsed time to set instead of a fixed interval, so the animation plays at a constant rate
    //only advance the animation timer if the simulation is not paused
    //and we haven't exceeded the max
    nextTime = paused || currentTime > maxTime ? currentTime : currentTime + elapsed;
    render(nextTime);
    d3.timer(callback(), interval);
```

Comment: Thanks! Animation does work, I just can't pause it. So, my understanding is that you've changed the inner function of the callback function (i.e. elapsed). There are two problems though: 1. How to get the elapsed time 2. How to call inner function of the callback with an argument (in d3.timer()...)? (I'm a novice as you can see!)

Comment: The elapsed time should automatically be handed to you when D3 calls you back (see the D3 docs). The inner function is what is returned by `callback()` and D3 will call it for you.

Comment: I've messed up sth there probably because it's not showing, but files are there

Comment: you've got JS errors `Uncaught ReferenceError: queue is not defined` in simVisMap.js and you have not defined the `getPausedState()` routine. You need to write that so that `paused` gets a valid value :)

Comment: well, queue is this : https://github.com/d3/d3-queue
the other one I don't know how to do!

Comment: Still has the same error. To implement `getPausedState()` all you do is toggle a variable when the user cilcks Start/Pause. Use an `onClick` handler for that button. They can even be one and the same button.